# How do you handle many GitHub Actions workflows in a monorepo?

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a monorepo on GitHub, it has ~10 APIs and ~10 frontends. Each are completely different codebases (beyond sharing some core logic) and each deploys to both `test` and `prod`.

Without knowing any better, teams have started creating deploy workflows for both `test` and `prod` in different files and putting them inside `/.github/workflows`. This was fine when we had a couple of workflows, but with at least two workflows for each project the amount of files has quickly grown out of proportion.

These deploy scripts need to be able to run both automatically whenever a PR is merged as well as manually via `workflow_dispatch`.

I initially thought I'd be able to use [different inputs](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-10-github-actions-input-types-for-manual-workflows/) and cut them down to one workflow per project, but these inputs wouldn't be available when running the workflow automatically on PR merge.

Is there a smarter way to handle this for monorepos? As far as I understand it you [can't really put workflows in subfolders](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/18055), how have you solved this issue?

Comment: Different workflow - different repository.

Comment: @Justinas It's a monorepo, they share code, so that's not an option unfortunately

Comment: Callable templates

Comment: @jessehouwing That might stop rewriting stuff in the workflows, but I'd still need the same exact workflows to call those templates? Unless I'm misunderstanding!

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to create multiple workflows each with their own triggers, name and such. That way they're also not triggering when their files haven't changed and such. Then call into templates to abstract away the implementations. I wouldn't use 2 workflows, one for `test` and one for `prod`, instead I'd use a single workflow with jobs and environments. Or a single workflow with the environment as an input.